# after jenkins building, return sh: next: not found error

Tags: docker, jenkins, next.js, jenkins-pipeline

When i finished my next.js project building jenkins, every step container was green(successful).
But In my ubuntu, when i did `docker ps -a`, my build contianer's status was Exited(127).
So i did `docker logs <continaerId>`, and i saw error as below.

```
> develop-order-service@0.1.0 start
> next start

sh: next: not found
```

i don't know what's wronng :-(
plz help :-((

- i installed nodejs in jenkins plugins
- my `docker-compose.yml` file code

```
version: "3.3"
services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        container_name: nginx
        volumes:
            - /nginx/certbot:/nginx/certbot
            - ./nginx/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
            - ./nginx/conf/develop-order-service.site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/develop-order-service.site.conf
        networks:
            - dos_docker
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        user: "0:0"
    jenkins:
        image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
        container_name: jenkins
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
            - "50000:50000"
        volumes:
            - /home/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
        networks:
            - dos_docker
        user: "0:0"
networks:
    dos_docker:
```

- my `develop-order-service.site.conf` file code

```
log_format  data  '$sent_http_X_DEBUG_MESSAGE';

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name develop-order-service.site;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  location / {
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name develop-order-service.site;

    ssl_certificate /nginx/certbot/conf/live/develop-order-service.site/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /nginx/certbot/conf/live/develop-order-service.site/privkey.pem;

  location / {
          resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
          resolver_timeout 10s;
          set $upstream http://develop-order-service.site;
          proxy_pass $upstream;
          proxy_set_header Host $host;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  }
}
```

- my `pipeline script` code

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    tools {nodejs "NODEJS"}
    
    stages {
        stage('Clone repository') {
            steps {
                script {
                    git branch: 'main', url: 'https://github.com/potato-club/develop-order-service.git'
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Check Dockerfile Path') {
            steps {
                sh 'ls -R'
            }
        }

        stage('Build Docker Image') {
            steps {
                dir('./') {
                    script {
                        def imageName = "dos:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
                        sh "docker build -t ${imageName} -f Dockerfile ."
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Run Docker container') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def customTag = "main"
                    def containerName = "DOS"
                    def imageName = "dos:${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"

                    def isContainerRunning = sh(script: "docker inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' ${containerName}", returnStatus: true)

                    if (isContainerRunning == 0) {
                        sh "docker rm -f ${containerName}"
                    }

                    sh "docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --network dos_docker -e TZ=Asia/Seoul --name ${containerName} ${imageName}"
                    echo "Docker container started!"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- my `Dockerfile` file code

```
FROM node:20.10.0-alpine AS base
FROM base AS deps
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi

FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

How can i solve this error :-<

Comment: In your final image, you don't `COPY` in the `node_modules` tree, or any other part of your application besides the (built?) `public` directory.  If you build and run the image locally (without Jenkins) does it work?  That might be an easier environment to debug.